# Printing the expanded macro to a file during compile time

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, macros

I'd like to get the result of a macro to be printed to a file at compile time for a gcc compiler.  I'd like to know if this is possible.  Example below:

```
#define MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(x)
```

expands to

```
(0x00000000u + (0x00040000u - ((uint32)(x) * 0x00000100u) - (64u)))
```

which computes to

```
0x0003ffd6
```

for

```
MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(0)
```

This is the address for some meta data for a bootloader, and I'd like to be able to use this address outside of runtime.

I've looked at #pragma message, but this only outputs the value to the gcc output, and not to a file.  It also has the inconvenience of having many other compiler messages mixed in.  Any hints or creative solutions welcomed.

Comment: You can use `gcc -E` to save the preprocessor output to a file. But the preprocessor doesn't perform the arithmetic, you'll just see `(0x00000000u + (0x00040000u - ((uint32)(0) * 0x00000100u) - (64u)))`

Comment: Couldn't you add an option to your program to make it print this data to a file? Then run the program with the option.

Comment: This is an embedded processor.

Comment: You don't have to run it on the embedded machine, the value of that macro is the same everywhere.

Comment: @Barmar: Building for a different target may cause some expressions to evaluate differently. A better solution is to generate inline assembly with GCC’s `__asm__` feature and include an operand with the `i` constraint, which is for immediate integer operands, as in `__asm__("#Use this value: %[foo]" : : [foo] "i" (MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(0)));`. Then compiling with `-S` and searching the generated assembly for the “Use this” line shows something like “##Use this value: $262080”. (The exact format may differ depending on target—“$” could be “#”, the comment marker could differ, and so on.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see how did you get `0x0003ffd6`, because I get `0x3ffc0`. Whatever.

Here I am going to describe three different methods of getting the result of expanded macro evaluation.

## 1. A `#pragma message` approach.

First, let's learn how to expand macros. This is done with double scan, you can read more about it at [C Preprocessor tricks, tips, and idioms](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms).

Suppose we have file expand.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint32_t uint32;

#define MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(x)\
    (0x00000000u + (0x00040000u - ((uint32)(x) * 0x00000100u) - (64u)))

#define STR(...) STR_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define STR_(...) # __VA_ARGS__

#pragma message "Value of MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(0) is " \
    STR(MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(0))

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(0));
}
```

After compiling, you'll have a complete expansion of a macro. You can duplicate it to a file with tee:

```
$ gcc expand.c 2>&1 | tee output
expand.c:11:9: note: #pragma message: Value of MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(0) is (0x00000000u + (0x00040000u - ((uint32)(0) * 0x00000100u) - (64u)))
   11 | #pragma message "Value of MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(0) is " \
      |         ^~~~~~~
```

Secondly, we need to catch out the expression. I will do it with sed:

```
$ pattern='.*note: \#pragma message: Value of MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET\(0\) is'
$ sed -E -ne "s/$pattern (.*)/\1/p" output
(0 + 0x00000000u + (0x00040000u - ((uint32)(0) * 0x00000100u) - (64u)))
```

`-n` suppresses the default output and `p` in the end of expression prints out only the matched string.

At last, evaluate the expression. I'd do it with python, or with bash directly, since they both support hex digits. But anyway, first we need to stripe out `(uint32)` conversions and `u` suffices specific to C and C++:

```
$ expr=$(sed -E -e 's/\(uint32\)//g' \
                -e 's/([0-9a-f]+)u/\1/g' \
                -ne "s/$pattern (.*)/\1/p" output)
$ printf "0x%016x\n" $(($expr))
0x000000000003ffc0
```

That's it!

## 2. Evaluation with host compiler.

Another way is to first get an output of cross-compiler `gcc -E`, e.g.

```
$ CC_CROSS=arm-noeabi-gcc
$ expr=$($CC_CROSS -E -xc - <<EOF
#include "your_header.h"
MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(0)
EOF | tail -n 1)
```

And then evaluate the expression with host compiler:

```
$ gcc -o get_md_btldb -xc - <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){ printf("%p", $expr); }
EOF
$ ./get_md_btldb
```

Should work as well, but didn't give it a try.

## 3. Take the value out of the binary directly!

Let's put a constant in your translation unit `value.c`:

```
typedef uint32_t uint32;

#define MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(x) \
    (0x00000000u + (0x00040000u - ((uint32)(x) * 0x00000100u) - (64u)))

uintptr_t MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET_VALUE = MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(0);
```

Now if you compile it to an object file, you will have a symbol in there:

```
$ gcc -c value.c
$ objdump -t -s -j.data value.o 

value.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 g     O .data  0000000000000008 MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET_VALUE


Contents of section .data:
 0000 c0ff0300 00000000                    ........
```

There it is, `c0ff0300 00000000`, written in little-endian format.
And the line

```
0000000000000000 g     O .data  0000000000000008 MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET_VALUE
```

Means that symbol `MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET_VALUE`'s value is lying at offset 0 in the section `.data` and has size 8. You can take it now there.

But it is easier to look at the disassembly:

```
$ gcc -S value.s
$ cat value.s
    .file   "value.c"
    .text
    .globl  MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET_VALUE
    .data
    .align 8
    .type   MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET_VALUE, @object
    .size   MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET_VALUE, 8
MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET_VALUE:
    .quad   262080
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 9.1.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The value goes right after the `MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET_VALUE` label:

```
MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET_VALUE:
    .quad   262080
```

Take it:

```
grep -A 1 -e 'MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET_VALUE:' value.s\
 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2;}'
 | xargs printf "%016x"

000000000003ffc0
```

Comment: What an answer!  Thank you for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to know certain bootloader addresses during the build phase is a common problem, you could try to add `-Xlinker -Map=output.map` to the gcc options and check if in the generated`.map` file there are the addresses that interest you.

Otherwise, you could have macro results compiled into a new section in the generated file, extract them with objcopy and / or some shell commands, and then remove the section from the compiled file (see comments in the example).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/**
 *
 * compile to a.out
 *    gcc -Wall -O2 addr.c
 * extract the section to a file (as raw binary) or dump on stdout:
 *    objcopy a.out /dev/null --dump-section .addrsec=/dev/stdout >addrsec.bin
 *    objcopy a.out /dev/null --dump-section .addrsec=/dev/stdout | od -t x4 -An
 * remove the section:
 *    objcopy --remove-section .addrsec a.out
 *
 **/

#define MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(x) (0x00000000u + (0x00040000u - ((uint32_t)(x) * 0x00000100u) - (64u)))

#define TEST_0 MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(0)
#define TEST_1 MD_BTLDB_APP_VERSION_OFFSET(1)

uint32_t addrvar[] __attribute__((section(".addrsec"))) = { TEST_0, TEST_1 };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("0x%08X\n", TEST_0);
    printf("0x%08X\n", TEST_1);
    return 0;
}
```